# toggleClass() does not work for me?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, toggleclass

I have a shopping bag in my page and i want pin and unpin this bag with toggleClass() jquery. To do this, i use a "fix" class, but my solution does not work. when i click on input button, "fix" class is added to li element but when i click on input button again, "fix" class will not be removed. Please help me. Thank you.

my .aspx:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>    
<li class="dropdown right transition">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">

    </a>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <div class="grid-container5">
            <div class="dropdown-inner form">
                //my Shopping bag
            </div>
            <input id="pin" type="submit" name="pin" value="" class="pin" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
</li>
</ul>
```

my jquery:

```
$(function () {
   $("#pin").click(function () {
      $(".menu li.dropdown").toggleClass("fix");
   });
});
```

Comment: Your code works fine: [http://jsfiddle.net/5zw7L0aL/](http://jsfiddle.net/5zw7L0aL/). Open the console and check it.

Comment: Oh, aspx, so that piece of code is inside a form. As @BorshonAeolusSaydur said in his answer, change the type of the input to button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats because you are using input type=submit..make it button it ll work... every time you click on submit button it submits the page back to CS page And posts back.And when it posts back The aspx page cannot rebind the jquery events with it .so you do not see its working after the postback.
if you make the input type button it will not postback and do its work as it is supposed to do.

Comment: Agree with @Borshon. Jquery statement in this case has no time to run since Submit is clicked page posted to the server and reloads to its original state. I would change code to this:

 <input id="pin" type="button" name="pin" value="" class="pin" />